# normalizing a non gaussian distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a set of empirical data that I have collected from different people with several attributes.  For privacy reasons I will refer to these attributes as a,b,c,d,... etc.  Since the data was collected from different people with slightly different reporting styles (I cannot assume that people perfectly report results the same way) I need to normalize each attribute across people.

For example, suppose I have two people that have given me several reports each with attributes a,b,c,... etc.  I cannot lump all the reports that I have gotten for attribute a from both users into one report.  I have to treat each person individually.  I would like to normalize my data to remove people from the equation so to speak so that I can lump the data that I have recorded into one report rather than individual reports for each person.

Some of the attributes are normally distributed, some are normally distributed and skewed, and some are not normally distributed.  Here are two example distributions of two different attributes.

[image: Attribute 1 distribution]

[image: Attribute 2 distribution]

Given an attribute a from sample s, the average of attribute a over a user i, avg, and the standard deviation of attribute a over user i, std, is it proper to normalize each attribute of my data set by this methodology, (sa - avg) / std?

Edit

All I want to do is remove user reporting variations.  For example a person may report on average 50 for attribute a while another user may report 90 on average.  Any further calculations that I will make will assume that reporting variations have been removed.

Will this result in me running into problems if I make further calculations with the data after normalizing?  Is there a  better way to do this?  Should I normalize the non gaussian distributions in another way?  Can I do what it is that I would like to do?

Thank you in advance for your insight

Comment: can you talk more about user reporting bias?  I cannot understand what kind of conclusion you want to obtain from all attributes. Therefore, it is difficult to say something, at least for me. Just a remark write the mathematical terms between these two signs \$\$.

Comment: Your two example deviations have strong censoring behaviour.  For instance, your second attribute should perhaps have a censored Gaussian fit with mean in the upper 80s and right censor at 100.  If you just take means and s.d.s, the censoring will introduce large bias.

Comment: I am not familiar with a censored Gaussian fit though I think I understand what you saying (statistics isn't my strong point).  How would I take censors into account (equation/link)?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören bias wasn't really the word I think.  I have corrected my explanation so that it is more clear.